# sklearn TimeSeriesSplit cross_val_predict only works for partitions

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, cross-validation

I am trying to use the TimeSeriesSplit cross-validation strategy in sklearn version 0.18.1 with a LogisticRegression estimator. I get an error stating that:

> cross_val_predict only works for partitions

The following code snippet shows how to reproduce:

```
from sklearn import linear_model, neighbors
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_predict, TimeSeriesSplit, KFold, cross_val_score
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date, datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,10,(100,5)), index=pd.date_range(start=date.today(), periods=100), columns='x1 x2 x3 x4 y'.split())


X, y = df['x1 x2 x3 x4'.split()], df['y']
score = cross_val_score(linear_model.LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=True), X, y, cv=TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=2))
y_hat = cross_val_predict(linear_model.LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=True), X, y, cv=TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=2), method='predict_proba')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How to use TimeSeriesSplit with cross_val_predict in a stacking context: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/105116/76808

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several ways to pass the `cv` argument in `cross_val_score`. Here you have to pass the generator for the splits. For example

```
y = range(14)
cv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=2).split(y)
```

gives a generator. With this you can generate the CV train and test index arrays. The first looks like this:

```
print cv.next()
    (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]), array([ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13]))
```

You can also take a dataframe as input for `split`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,10,(100,5)), 
                  index=pd.date_range(start=date.today(), 
                  periods=100), columns='x1 x2 x3 x4 y'.split())

cv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=2).split(df)
print cv.next()
    (array([ 0,  1,  2, ..., 31, 32, 33]), array([34, 35, 36, ..., 64, 65, 66]))
```

In your case this should work:

```
score = cross_val_score(linear_model.LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=True), 
                         X, y, cv=TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=2).split(df))
```

Have a look at [cross_val_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score) and [TimeSeriesSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit) for details.

Comment: What is `14` here in `range(14)`? Is that some arbitrary number? Same with the dataframe values. Its not super clear to me how you came to these values.

Comment: The 14 is arbitrary and - as stated - an example. Regarding the dataframe: Have a look at the question, I just copied it.